# ASP.NET Development server inaccessible

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devforce

I've been working on a home project using VS2008. It involves WCF and Silverlight. Until recently, ASP.NET development server worked just fine and was accessible from the browsers (I use both FF and IE). Now, it seems the browsers are no longer able to access the asp.net dev server. Initially, I believed it to be certain installations I had made (DevForce Silverlight and MVC 1.0) But after uninstalling, it still did not fix the problem. I then tried disabling IPv6 as some websites suggested and I was not using proxies, so that wasn't the problem either.

Has this happened to anyone else? Have you been able to solve the problem or at least find the reason for it?
(I just bypassed it by using IIS instead)

Comment: Is there a specific error message? Some personal firewall port issues?

Comment: No firewall issues. I've completely shut down all firewalls to check it. The message is the standard messages for each of the browsers when a website is simply inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was in the hosts file.

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

I managed to solve this problem according to a post [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1395973.aspx).

I chose to add the **127.0.0.1   localhost** rather than removing or commenting out the **::1             localhost** but I tried both and both solutions definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the list of running processes on that machine to make sure there isn't another instance of the dev server running? If so, you may have to kill it to get it to start fresh.

Another possibility would be to reboot that machine and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried going through processes and killing them until the problem was solved, but to no avail. I rebooted plenty of times as well, also with no luck.